# Django: 'created' cannot be specified for Order model form as it is a non-editable field

Tags: python, django

I've a model called Order, that stores information about the order placed by each user.

This order has a field `created` that I want to display in the `admin panel` but I'm getting this error:

```
FieldError at /admin/order/order/1/change/

'created' cannot be specified for Order model form as it is a non-editable field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class OrderAdmin.
```

**models.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    token = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=250, blank = True, verbose_name= 'Correo electrónico')
    last_four = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    shipping_address1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_address2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_department = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_province = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    shipping_district = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True, default='')


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Order'
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)




class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name= 'PEN Price')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



    class Meta:
        db_table = "OrderItem"

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price


    @property
    def image_filename(self):
        return self.image.url.split('/')[-1]


    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Order, OrderItem


class OrderItemAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    fieldsets = [
        # ('Customer', {'fields': ['first_name', 'last_name'], }),
        ('Product', {'fields': ['product'],}),
        ('Quantity', {'fields': ['quantity'],}),
        ('Price', {'fields': ['price'], }),
    ]
    readonly_fields = ['product', 'quantity', 'price']
    can_delete = False
    max_num = 0
    template = 'admin/order/tabular.html'

### Order Display ###



@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Order
    list_display = ['token', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'total', 'reason', 'created']
    list_editable = ['reason',]
    list_display_links = ('token', 'email')
    search_fields = ['token', 'shipping_department', 'email']
    fieldsets = [
        ('ORDER INFORMATION', {'fields': ['token', 'total', 'created']}),            
        ('SHIPPING INFORMATION', {'fields': ['first_name', 'last_name', 'shipping_department', 'shipping_province',
                                             'shipping_district']}),
    ]

    inlines = [
        OrderItemAdmin,
    ]

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

Comment: Hello, Are you trying to modify the created value in the admin ?
If yes you should change its `auto_add_now=True` parameter to `default=timezone.now` - from `django.utils.timezone.now()`
see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Comment: @Taek No, I just want to show the created value in the admin panel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add `readonly_fields` to your `OrderAdmin`, and add `created` to that list, such as:

```
@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    readonly_fields = ['created']
```

[The Django docs describe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) that when using `fieldsets` which contain read-only fields, those fields must be listed in `readonly_fields` for them to be displayed.

Comment: How may I include a `readonly_fields`'s field in the template to display model inlineformset fields as we do for other (_editable_) fields?